# SQL Import and Export Wizard

Tags: sql-server, excel, sql-server-2012

I need to import an Excel file into a SQL Server 2012 database. It will contain around 12,000 rows every month. I know I can use the wizard to perform this task but I would like to delete the rows from the destination table if they match the ID number of the data being imported.

Would I be able to import the data into a temp table then do the match/delete all in one script via the wizard?

Should I be rather looking at another method?

Thanks

Comment: Well, you could create a "raw table", then insert into target table and truncate the raw table afterwards. Or there are ways to directly access Excel with SQL. Or you could create an SSIS package to do it for you. Or you could create a trigger, keep in mind that insert triggers by default don't fire when you use the import-export wizard so you'll have to change a setting for that.

Comment: I think it would be easier for you to look for SSIS. You can do this easily

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is actually a way to query an Excel file the same way you might do to a table, and it would allow you to pretty easily do what you described. With that said, there is a little bit of preliminary legwork to get it to work.

For this explanation, I tested locally with an xlsx file (created with Excel 2013) with a single sheet `Sheet1` with two columns, the first row containing the column names `Field1` and `Field2`.

Here is what I am able to do currently.

```
--SELECT from Sheet1 into a local temp table
SELECT * INTO #TempTable
FROM OPENROWSET('Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0',
  'Excel 12.0 Xml;
   Database=C:\Users\pwalton\Documents\test.xlsx',
   [Sheet1$]);

--Clear out the original records
DELETE FROM TestImportTable
WHERE Field1 IN (SELECT Field1 FROM #TempTable)

--Insert the new ones
INSERT INTO TestImportTable
SELECT * FROM #TempTable

--Get rid of the evidence!
DROP TABLE #TempTable
```

Here's what I needed to to to get to this point.

1. I downloaded and installed [2007 Office System Driver: Data Connectivity Components](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx%3Fid%3D23734).
2. I had to enable ad hoc queries, with the following command.

   ```
   EXEC sp_configure 'show advanced options', 1
   RECONFIGURE
   GO
   EXEC sp_configure 'ad hoc distributed queries', 1
   RECONFIGURE
   GO
   ```
3. I had to make sure that I was running SQL Server Management Studio as a system admin. In my case, I needed to shift right-click and *Run as administrator*. If you are in a more managed environment, work with your Network Administrator to get the correct rights.

That should be all you need. Again, I tested this locally, and each of the items I listed above were needed to overcome particular errors along the way.